# Sending 'CLLocationCoordinate2D' to parameter of incomparable type 'CLLocationCoordinate2D *'

Tags: objective-c, pointers, delegates

When compiling, I'm getting the following error when trying to return coordinates to the class' delegate method.

Sending 'CLLocationCoordinate2D' to parameter of incomparable type 'CLLocationCoordinate2D *'

I understand it must be to do with pointers, but I'm not too sure about how to resolve it.

Comment: No, this means that the receiver is not expecting a CLLocationCoordinate2D but some other type of data. You should post us some code, so we can help. I can only guess that the receiver might expect a CLLocation instead of a CLLocationCoordinate2D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take the address and return that:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D thing;
[delegate methodcall:&thing];
```